# Cómo podría lograr que la función me elimine el patrón cada vez que se repita? traté de hacerlo con un for y tampoco resultó

Tags: javascript

Programa una función que elimine cierto patrón de caracteres de un texto dado, pe. miFuncion("xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5", "xyz") devolverá  "1, 2, 3, 4 y 5".

```js
function eliminarCaracteres(str = '', patron = '') {

  var replace = /xyz/gi

  var newStr = str.replace(patron, '', 'gi')

  console.log(newStr)
}

eliminarCaracteres("xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5", "xyz")
```

**Esto retorna '1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5'***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo debes cambiar replace por replaceAll

ejemplo

```js
function eliminarCaracteres(str = '', patron = '') {

    var replace = /xyz/gi

    // cambiar replace por replaceAll
    var newStr = str.replaceAll(patron, '', 'gi')

    console.log(newStr)
}

eliminarCaracteres("xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5", "xyz")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! muchas veces una bobada te puede trabar mucho jaja

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres mantener el uso de expresiones regulares (para casos más complejos) usando el `patron` dentro de ellas, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es crear la regex con [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) para poder hacerla dinámica utilizando las banderas ya utilizadas (lla i no es necesaria a menos que quiera que funcione tanto para mayúsculas como minúsculas), de este modo se puede seguir haciendo uso del método [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) con la regex generada.

```js
function eliminarCaracteres(str = '', patron = '') {
  // Construir la regex con el patrón incluido
  const regex = new RegExp(`${patron}`, 'g');

  return str.replace(regex, '');
}

console.log(eliminarCaracteres('xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, xyz4 y xyz5', 'xyz'));
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! empecé hace poco y hay muchos métodos que aún no conozco, pero intentaba hacerlo de la forma más básica posible sin utilizar Console ni nada para entender bien la lógica.